# If the value of particular ID does not exist in another ID, insert row with value to ID

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to update and insert a new row, if D1 value is not existing in other ID's, whilst my df['Value'] is left blank (N/A). Your help is appreciated.

Input

```
D1     ID   Value
0.02   1    1.2
0.04   1    1.6
0.06   1    1.9
0.08   1    2.8
0.02   2    4.5
0.04   2    4.1
0.08   2    3.6
0.02   3    2.7
0.04   3    2.9
0.06   3    2.4
0.08   3    2.1
0.1    3    1.9
```

Expected output:

```
D1     ID   Value
0.02   1    1.2
0.04   1    1.6
0.06   1    1.9
0.08   1    2.8
0.1    1   
0.02   2    4.5
0.04   2    4.1
0.06   2    
0.08   2    3.6
0.1    2   
0.02   3    2.7
0.04   3    2.9
0.06   3    2.4
0.08   3    2.1
0.1    3    1.9
```

Unfortunately the codes I have written have been way off or simply gets multiple error messages, unlike my other questions I do not have examples to show.

Comment: could you explain a bit further, cos I dont see any of D1 in the ID column, certainly 0.02 is not in ID.

Comment: Question has been answered, its the values of D1 that are linked to an ID, so if another ID does not have the exact same D1 values, then I would need to populate this into the current ID. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unstack` and `stack`. Chain additional `sort_index` and `reset_index` to achieve desired order

```
df_final = (df.set_index(['D1', 'ID']).unstack().stack(dropna=False)
              .sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index())

Out[952]:
      D1  ID  Value
0   0.02   1    1.2
1   0.04   1    1.6
2   0.06   1    1.9
3   0.08   1    2.8
4   0.10   1    NaN
5   0.02   2    4.5
6   0.04   2    4.1
7   0.06   2    NaN
8   0.08   2    3.6
9   0.10   2    NaN
10  0.02   3    2.7
11  0.04   3    2.9
12  0.06   3    2.4
13  0.08   3    2.1
14  0.10   3    1.9
```